# How to calculate p-value from a linear mixed effect model created by lme4::lmer() using broom::tidy()?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, p-value, broom

I have a built a mixed effect model using the `lmer()` function from the `lme4` package. The `lme4` package does not output the p-value of the coefficients for some good philosophical reason. However, I still need p-values to report in my publication. I know there are multiple ways to calculate p-values using the model created by `lmer()`, e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118416/getting-p-value-with-mixed-effect-with-lme4-package).

My problem is: I want to extract p-value using the `tidy()` function from the `broom` package. Here, I really want to stick with `tidy()` because I want to maintain the following pipeline:

```
data_frame %>% group_by(grouping variables) %>% do(tidy(fitted_model))
```

One option would be to create a custom function and append it to the pipeline. However, the man page of the `broom` package (http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/broom/man/lme4_tidiers.html) says:

```
"p.value  P-value computed from t-statistic (may be missing/NA)".
```

By this I am assuming a function to calculate p-value from the t-value given by lmer model has already been implemented in broom. So, I am reluctant to reinvent the wheel.

The problem is I don't get the column with name p.value at all. I was expecting a column named p.value with NAs as the worst case scenario.

Code:

```
library(lme4)
library(broom)
lme <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
tidy(lme)
tidy(lme, effects = "fixed")
```

Output:

```
> tidy(lme)
                         term     estimate std.error statistic    group
1                  (Intercept) 251.40510485  6.824557 36.838306    fixed
2                         Days  10.46728596  1.545789  6.771485    fixed
3       sd_(Intercept).Subject  24.74045195        NA        NA  Subject
4              sd_Days.Subject   5.92213312        NA        NA  Subject
5 cor_(Intercept).Days.Subject   0.06555113        NA        NA  Subject
6      sd_Observation.Residual  25.59181564        NA        NA Residual
> tidy(lme, effects = "fixed")
         term  estimate std.error statistic
1 (Intercept) 251.40510  6.824557 36.838306
2        Days  10.46729  1.545789  6.771485
```

Comment: It looks like you will have to calculate p-values yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need package `lmerTest` to obtain p-values. `tidy` will not work on the `lme` object and you will need to append it to your format.

```
attach(mtcars)
lme <- lmer(mpg ~ cyl + (1 + cyl | carb), mtcars)
summary(lme)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sjstats::p_value()` to get p-values from many different models, including (generalized) mixed models.

Comment: In the latest version, `sjstats::p_value()` is deprecated, so you should use `parameters::p_value()`.